# How come a thread leave lines behind?

Tags: java, for-loop, jvm, java-threads

I'm new to programming and been studying threads for some time now.

So, the following code should give an output of:

```
one 98098
two 98099
```

and it does sometimes.

When I try to run it for a couple of times, it gives different outputs. I can understand that the JVM controls the threads and I can't directly affect it, but some of the outputs are less than 98,000 even though the for loop is adding 1000 for 98 times. How is this happening? Can a thread leave lines behind? Or did I do something wrong (note: the expected output sometimes shows on the screen, but not always)

```java
public class TestThreads {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ThreadOne t1 = new ThreadOne();
        Thread one = new Thread(t1);
        ThreadTwo t2 = new ThreadTwo();
        Thread two = new Thread(t2);
        one.start();    
        two.start();
    }
}
class Accum {
    private int counter = 0;
    private static Accum a = new Accum();
    private Accum() {
    }
    public static Accum getAccum() {
        return a;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return counter;
    }
    public void updateCounter(int add) {
        counter += add;
    }
}

class ThreadOne implements Runnable {
    Accum a = Accum.getAccum();
    public void run() {
        for(int x=0; x < 98; x++) {
            a.updateCounter(1000);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) { }
        }
        System.out.println("one "+a.getCount());
    }
}

class ThreadTwo implements Runnable {
    Accum a = Accum.getAccum();
    public void run() {
        for(int x=0; x < 99; x++) {
            a.updateCounter(1);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) { }
        }
        System.out.println("two "+a.getCount());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read up on the atomicity of shared data and racing conditions. In your code it is very likely that `ThreadTwo` finishes before `ThreadOne` and thus when it prints the value of `a` that value might be well below 98000. Also note that `counter += add;` isn't an atomic operation and thus there's no guarantee the final value will be 98099 - the operations triggered by both threads could be executed at exactly the same time and thus mixed which might result in unexpected values. I'd suggest researching and using `AtomicInteger` instead.

Comment: Your code isn't thread safe, reading the value of a variable, adding to it, and writing the value back are multiple operations, which means the operations of threads can interleave, where both read the same value, add a value, and then write it back, and then the last to write "wins". Also, with not thread-safe code, threads don't necessarily see each others updates (though I believe the sleep will prevent that in this case).

Comment: Please don't undo improvements done to your posts. Stack Overflow allows and encourages community members to edit posts to fix typos, formatting errors, etc. I have rolled back your edit that destroyed my edit.

Comment: Your accumulator is not thread-safe. It neads to be protected in one way or another,

Comment: update : i tried the **AtomicInteger** way and this inspired me to use **synchronized block** on 'a.updateCounter' the two ways gave same results (two outputs only) :
one 98099
two 98099
(or)
one 98098
two 98099
i know the problem is not solved entirely but in general I understand the problem now so thank you all

Comment: @AliMajor That is because one thread might be printing the results while the other one isn't finished yet. You could solve that with a `CountDownLatch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your `updateCounter` method isn't thread-safe. If it's called from two threads at the same time, you can lose information.

Let's rewrite it to make it more obvious why that's the case:

```java
public void updateCounter(int add) {
    // Fetch
    int originalValue = counter;
    // Compute
    int newValue = originalValue + add;
    // Store
    counter = newValue;
}
```

Imagine what happens if two threads come into the method at the same time. We'll pretend that there's some "total ordering" of what happens - the reality is more complex than that, but even the simplified form shows the problem. Suppose `counter` has a value of 5 to start with, and on thread x we're calling `updateCounter(3)` and on thread y we're calling `updateCounter(4)`. We could imagine this sequence of events:

1. Thread x executes the "fetch" operation: `originalValue = 5` (local variable, unaffected by thread y)
2. Thread y executes the "fetch" operation: `originalValue = 5`
3. Thread x executes the "compute" operation: `newValue = 8`
4. Thread y executes the "compute" operation: `newValue = 9`
5. Thread x executes the "store" operation: `counter = 8` (note that `newValue` in thread x is separate to the one in thread y)
6. Thread y executes the "store" operation: `counter = 9`

So we end up with the value of `counter` being 9... as if the `updateCounter(3)` call had never taken place. If the last two operations happened in the reverse order, then `counter` would be 8 instead.

The way to fix this is to use the [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) class which is designed specifically to make operations like this *atomic*:

```java
class Accum {
    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static Accum a = new Accum();

    private Accum() {
    }

    public static Accum getAccum() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return counter.get();
    }

    public void updateCounter(int add) {
        counter.addAndGet(add);
    }
}
```